# How to wait for multiple requests based on _.each iteration in angular using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Hi I have a method that does multiple request based on _.each iteration. What I want to do is initialize `vm.job = job` in the `getAllJobSublinesByJobline` after the _.each iteration

```
    var vm = this;

    function getAllJobSublinesByJobline () {
        return $resource( '/api/joblines/get_all_jobsublines_by_jobline/:pageLimit', {
            'jobLineId' : '@jobLineId',
            'page'      : '@page',
            'search'    : '@search',
            'sortField' : '@sortField',
            'sortType'  : '@sortType'
        } );
    }

    function getJobsublinesByJoblineId ( joblines, job ) {
        _.each( joblines, function ( jobline ) {
            if ( parseInt( jobline.num_sublines ) ) {
                var jobsublineFetchDetails = {
                    'pageLimit' : 10,
                    'jobLineId' : jobline.id
                };
                return getAllJobSublinesByJobline().save( jobsublineFetchDetails ).$promise.then( function ( jobsubline ) {
                    jobline.jobsublines = jobsubline.data;
                    job.joblines.push( jobline );
                } );
            }
            job.joblines.push( jobline );
        } );
        vm.job = job; // initializes right away even though _.each iteration is not finished yet
    }
```

My problem is that it initializes right away even though the _.each iteration has not finished fetching data yet. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is the nature of javascript it interpreter every line in your file and add any callback to the stack. After your file is interpreted then the javascript engine will run the callbacks in the stack. So when `getJobsublinesByJoblineId` is called it executes the whole body of the function and pass your `_.each` callback to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

-- [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

So as said in another answer, push promises, and use `$q.all`.

```
function getJobsublinesByJoblineId ( joblines, job ) {
    var promises = [];
    _.each( joblines, function ( jobline ) {
        if ( parseInt( jobline.num_sublines ) ) {
            var jobParams = {
                'pageLimit' : 10,
                'jobLineId' : jobline.id
            };
            var details = getAllJobSublinesByJobline().save( jobParams );
            promises.push(details.$promise);
        }
    } );
    $q.all(promises).then (function (detailsArray) {
         //assemble job object
         vm.job = job;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably push all promises to an array and  use something like

```
$q.all(yourPromises).then(function(allCompletedResponse){...}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to initialize the jobline on having the jobsubline what I did with mine was similar to the answer above.

```
    function getJobsublinesByJoblineId ( joblines, job ) {
        var promises = _.map( joblines, function ( jobline ) {
            var jobParams = {
                'jobLineId' : jobline.id
            };

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            apiService.getAllJobSublinesByJobline().save( jobParams ).$promise.then( function ( jobsubline ) {
                jobline.jobsublines = jobsubline.data;
                deferred.resolve( jobline );
            } );

            return deferred.promise;
        } );

        $q.all( promises ).then( function ( joblines ) {
            job.joblines = joblines
            vm.job       = job;
        } );
    }
```